# Create ArrayList of Bitmap thumbnails

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bitmap

I am trying to create an application that shows multiple wallpapers which can be set at a button press. Threrfore I created a ViewPager with 10 different Fragments. Each fragment should show a section of the wallpaper in full screen. The problem is, that the wallpapers are very high definition (3000*2500) which causes in an OutOfMemoryException. This is why I first wanted to generate an ArrayList full of Bitmaps of the screen size instead of this high resolution. Still, I get an OutOfMemoryException. Here's my code how I tried to achieve this:

```
public ArrayList<Bitmap> createThumbnails() {
    ArrayList<Bitmap> result = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {

        //Bitmaps will be loaded here by resource, they're called w_0, w_1, w_2...

        Bitmap b0 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getResources().getIdentifier("w_" + i, "drawable", getPackageName()));

        //Here the thumbnail gets created with new Dimensions (screenWidth and screenHeight)

        Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(b0, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

        //The full-sized Bitmap gets recycled to gain some memory back

        b0.recycle();

        //The resized Bitmap 'b1' gets added to the ArrayList and the loop repeats

        result.add(b1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a better solution for my problem? I've got several wallpapers with different side-ratios. I just want to get the dimension of the screen cut out of this wallpaper and show it in full-screen. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This way is memory consuming. Try : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18015841/1531054

Answer (score 1):

The image you are trying to load in your thumbnail typically requires about 7MB which in turn could produce out of memory. You need to scale down your image to a smaller size before displaying it in your thumbnail.

Android training center has this topic [handling bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) will help you to address your issue.

Comment: If I scale down the just produced image, how can I stretch it to full-screen? I've set my ImageView properties both to "match_parent", is the stretching done automatically? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @user2410644 You can use the `setScaleType` of the view to determine how you would like for your wallpaper to be displayed, which might be a form of crop most likely.  You might even need to use `setAdjustViewBounds(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to provide a segment that shows them small thumbnails, then you should load in small thumbnails at an appropriate size.  Don't load the images at full size.  If you have control over the resources, then I would just load in like 300 x 250 small thumbnails there.  When they select the appropriate thumbnail, then use that as a map to your full-blown image that it corresponds to and load that.

It would also be best to make sure that it will fit in memory.  There are several ways to do that following the [loading of bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) link provided by Google.  However

```
private Bitmap getImage(String path)
{
    try
    {
        final int sizeFactors[] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 };

        if (new File(path).exists())
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeFactors.length; ++i)
            {
                try
                {
                     options.inSampleSize = sizeFactors[i];
                     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

                     if(bmp.getHeight() > MyImageView.MAXIMUM_BITMAP_HEIGHT ||
                        bmp.getWidth() > MyImageView.MAXIMUM_BITMAP_WIDTH)
                     {
                        continue;
                     }

                        /*
                         * @category Check against EXIF data if the image needs to be rotated or not for viewing.
                         */
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix ();
                        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path); 
                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt (ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1); 
                        switch(orientation) 
                        { 
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                                break; 
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: 
                                matrix.postRotate (90); 
                                break; 
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: 
                                matrix.postRotate (180);
                                break; 
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                matrix.postRotate (270); 
                                break; 
                            default: 
                        } 

                        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap (bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth (), bmp.getHeight (), matrix, true);

                        return bmp;
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemory)
                    {
                        Log.d("MyLog", "Resampling to fit the image on the screen.");
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception("Not enough memory for loading image");
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.w("MyLog", "Exception.");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing the bitmap before displaying.

If that's not what you want, 
Then do this

In your manifest file, set
android: LargeHeap = "true"

If that still doesn't satisfy you, then you'd have to hold the bitmap outside java---->.  https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations

Comment: That's my idea. I first create the ArrayList with this code snippet I've posted and try to paint these "thumbnails" of the real image.

Comment: An arraylist of bitmaps is very heavy for the memory. Maybe you should try an arraylist of the bitmap url or File paths.

Comment: All bitmaps are shown in a ViewPager so I guess they're all shown simultanuously, does it make a difference if they're drawn via an ArrayList or loaded (simultanuously) by their URL?

Comment: Holding the bitmaps in an array is like inviting all your friends at your school into your room at once. You should only create bitmaps the instant you need them and Release them the instant you are done with it

Comment: so it doesnt matter if its shown in a ViewPager or not. the memory Allocated to the bitmap still counts. so yes it makes a difference.